# react native - How to use state in constructor

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to use a state in definition of an other state but i get nothing value.
Does anyone have any ideas??

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

        check : false,
        datatotal : this.props.services.map((d) =>
            <CheckBox
                center
                title={d}
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked= {true}
                onPress={() => this.checkBoxClick()}
            />
    )

    };


}
```

Comment: `use a state in definition of an other state but i get nothing value`, what does it means? can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this inside your Component

```
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
  this.state = {
     check: false
   } 
} 

render() {
 <View>
 {this.props.services && this.props.services.map(
  <CheckBox
            center
            title={d}
            checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
            uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
            checked= {true}
            onPress={() => this.checkBoxClick()}
        />
  )</View>}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey checkout this link it might help you : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_state.htm